# isdigit function is not catching mixed values in argv[]

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check for correct 1 integer argument else print instructions
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        printf("plaintext: ");    
        printf("rawtext: ");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: [KEY]\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

The program should print "Usage: [KEY]" if the user enters  ./program 2z but isdigit is not catching "z". Is there a way to correct this or is there any other alternative to isdigit function?

Comment: `isdigit()` just checks a single character, not a string.

Comment: All the `isXXX()` functions only check one character at a time.

Comment: You only use `isdigit` with the first character in the input.

Comment: That's why you have to use `*argv[1]`. If it processed the string, it would take the entire `argv[1]` value as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `isdigit()` in a loop, testing each character, since it only checks one character at a time.

```
if (argc == 2 && argv[1][0]) {
    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]) {
            printf("Error: key must be numeric\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("plaintext: ");    
    printf("rawtext: ");
    return 0;
} else {
    printf("Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
```